# BTCUSD mean value

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate

Recently I've heard of a site which gathers prices from some exchanges, and gives you a mean value.

I've tried googling for it and I failed, couldn't find anything related for some reason.

Could you point me out to such a site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BitcoinAverage](http://bitcoinaverage.com/) launched just recently. According to [their post on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1jl9c2/bitcoinaveragecom/) the prices shown

> - are a daily weighted average
> - factor in all exchanges currently with available data
> - are near-live rates

You can hover the mouse over the price to get more details on what exchanges are used and their weight.

Comment: It wasn't this one but I don't care: this one is fine enough anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Probably this is more informative and partly older than BitcoinAverage:

http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/

> Introduction
>
> Bitcoincharts provides financial and technical data related to the
>   Bitcoin network. You can also access this data via our JSON-API.
>
> Market overview
>
> Bitcoincharts uses daily intervals (UTC) to display data. For example,
>   the volume of a market will usually be zero at midnight (UTC) and
>   increase during the day.